# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while clicking on submit button

Tags: asp.net

I have created a webpage in asp.net [image]

on right hand side I have an ListBox which binds data from database when page loads, Its code at Default.aspx is as below

```
  <asp:ListBox ID="ListOfSql" runat="server"  
        SelectionMode="Single" DataTextField="sql_name" DataValueField="sql_text" 
        style="margin-left: 0px; width:auto; height:300px" EnableViewState="true">
 </asp:ListBox>
```

and at default.aspx.cs page its code is

```
 private void loadSqlList()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string preSql = "select sql_name, sql_text from cn_sql_log order by sql_name";
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(preSql, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
            ListOfSql.DataSource = ds;
            ListOfSql.DataTextField = "Sql_Name";
            ListOfSql.DataValueField = "sql_Text";
            ListOfSql.DataBind();
            ListOfSql.SelectedIndex = 0;
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I am calling **loadSqlList()** on page_load so that I can get list from database in ListBox.
Now I have an submit button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPreSqlExe" runat="server" Text="Sumbit" 
                onclick="btnPreSqlExe_Click">
 </asp:Button>
```

on default.aspx.cs page submit button's code is

```
 protected void btnPreSqlExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtQuery.Text = ListOfSql.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
    }
```

Now when I want that on clicking on submit button then text of selected item should appear in textbox which is at left hand side
when I do so I am getting an error page

[image]

complete code of default.aspx.cs page is as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source = orcl; user id=*****;password = *****; unicode = true;");
    //OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=orcl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=system;password = ravi_123;Unicode=True");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {    
        }
        loadSqlList();
        lblLastRefresh.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
        //=============================================  Checking user logged in or not ===================================
        //if (Session["txtUserName"] == null)
        //{
        //    Response.Write("<Script Language ='JavaScript'> alert('Session Expired, please login again')</script>");
        //    conn.Close();
        //    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        //}
        //=============================================  Checking user logged in or not (END) =================================== 


        //=====================User Ip Tracer =======================

        string UserIp = Request.ServerVariables["http_x_forwarded_for"];
        string UserHost = Request.ServerVariables["http_X_forwarded_for"];
        string userMacAdd = Request.ServerVariables["http_x_forwarde_for"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserIp))
        {
            UserIp = Request.ServerVariables["Remote_ADDR"];
            UserHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        }
        LblLoc.Text = UserIp;
        LblHostName.Text = UserHost;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        //=====================User Ip Tracer code end =======================

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }

    }
    protected void onclick_logout(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Close();
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
    protected void exportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            conn.Open();
            string sql;
            sql = txtQuery.Text.ToString();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn);

            //================  User Details Data Insertion in DataBase Ends here ===============
            da.Fill(dt);
            ExportTableData(dt);
            Response.Write("<Script>alert('Ip Locked in DB')</Script>");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString();

        }
    }
    protected void btnClear_clik(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtQuery.Text = string.Empty;

    }
    private void ExportTableData(DataTable dtdata)
    {
        string attach = "attachment;filename="+ListOfSql.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()+".xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attach);
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        if (dtdata != null)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dtdata.Columns)
            {
                Response.Write(dc.ColumnName + "\t");
            }
            Response.Write(System.Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtdata.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtdata.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    Response.Write(dr[i].ToString() + "\t");
                }
                Response.Write("\n");
            }
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    // References for this page 
   // http://forums.asp.net/t/1768549.aspx





    protected void btnPreSqlExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtQuery.Text = ListOfSql.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
    }

    private void loadSqlList()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string preSql = "select sql_name, sql_text from cn_sql_log order by sql_name";
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(preSql, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
            ListOfSql.DataSource = ds;
            ListOfSql.DataTextField = "Sql_Name";
            ListOfSql.DataValueField = "sql_Text";
            ListOfSql.DataBind();
            ListOfSql.SelectedIndex = 0;
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a selection isn't made then `ListOfSql.SelectedItem` will be null, and therefore calling `.Text` on that will result in your error.

Try changing your code to something like this:

```
protected void btnPreSqlExe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ListOfSql.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        txtQuery.Text = ListOfSql.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: By doing so, error page will be removed but I'll not get listbox's text value to textbox which is at left hand side.

Comment: Do you get that error when an item is selected? My solution will solve your problem when an item in the list isn't selected and the button is pressed.

Comment: actually, after selecting any item from listbox and by pressing submit button because of **POSTBACK** value of selected item becomes null again.